# Google Analytics Data API cost after reaching usage limit: What are the charges per additional row of data processed?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4, data-processing

I'm using the Google Analytics Data API for my project, and I'm trying to understand the cost implications if I exceed the usage limits of the free quota.

Specifically, I want to know how much I will be charged for each additional row of data processed after reaching the limit, and whether there are any other fees or charges that I should be aware of.

As of now, the free quota includes 25,000 core tokens per property per day, 5,000 core tokens per property per hour, and 1,750 core tokens per project per property per hour. Can someone help me understand how the pricing structure works for the Google Analytics Data API and provide me with information on the cost after reaching the limit?

Any help or advice on this topic would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!